# How to make this shape in html?

Tags: html, shapes

How to make this shape in html?
In need to code it in table and put text labels inside.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use transform in your css.
 following code will help you.

```html
<div id="parallelogram"></div>
<style>
  #parallelogram {
 width: 200px;
 height: 20px;
 -webkit-transform: skew(149deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(149deg);
      -o-transform: skew(149deg);
 background: #005999;
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

background gradients works too, then no need to deal with transform as well for content.

```css
/* 2 gradients side by side */
p, div  {
  color:lightgray;
  padding:0.25em 2em;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg,transparent 1.5em, #00367C 1.25em, #00367C 55%, transparent 55%),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent 1.5em, #00367C 1.25em, #00367C 55%, transparent 55%);
  }
/* or a single gradient sized with calc() */
div {
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg,
      transparent 1.5em, 
      #a0367C 1.25em, 
      #a0367C calc(100% - 1.5em) , 
      transparent calc(100% - 1.5em)
    )
    ;
  }

label {
  color:white;
  }
```

```html
<p><label>label</label> or some text or <input value="input" />or whatever on a single line</p>
<div><label>label</label> or some text or <input value="input" />or whatever on a single line</div>
```